# Show title and image of all Shopify products within drop down menu

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I'm working on a "bundling" feature for my store and would like to show all my products within a custom form field.

I would like there to be a dropdown menu showing the title and primary image for each product.

I'm thinking the code should be something like this:

```html
<p class="line-item-property__field">
  <label>bundled item</label><br>
  <select required class="required" id="bundled-item" name="properties[bundled item]">
    {% for product in collections.products %}
      <option value="{{ product.title }}">{{ product.title }}{{ product.featured_image }}</option>

    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</p>
```

That doesn't quite do it though.  Can anyone show the proper way to embed products within a dropdown?

Comment: I would say this typeahead like autocomplete is the closest that is supported with shopify https://docs.shopify.com/support/configuration/store-customization/can-i-add-autocomplete-to-my-storefront-search-boxes I can see reason why you should not as this UI is not ideal for selecting products.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    {% for product in collections['all'].products %}
      <option value="{{ product.title }}">{{ product.title }}{{ product.featured_image }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
```

But remember, only a maximum of 1000 items can be called in a loop; by default it is 50.

Comment: What is I have two dropdowns, and when I select one product in one dropdown that product will be disabled in the second dropdown.

Comment: @AnupamMistry you'll need to apply JavaScript logic there.